# Reply to a rejection email

Tags: formal-language

I've got an email about rejecting the sponsorship letter. Is it polite to reply with *"Noted and thank you for your kind assistance in this matter."* ?

Comment: They probably do not expect a response, but I do not know full context. I would suggest that any response you make be worded in such a way as to not oblige the recipient to respond.  your wording seems apropriate.   This question might be better asked on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to formally reply to the rejection email, I would elaborate a bit on your Original reply like this:

> Thank you for notifying me of the rejection and for your assistance in this matter.

Don't forget to start and end the email with a formal salutation and sign off.